# Как мне не искать каждый раз пользователя в Spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

В общем при каждом обращении к котроллер в Spring мне приходится искать пользователя, создавать объект и уже работать с ним. Т.е. скажем захожу в /profile, я вытаскиваю имя авторизованного пользователя, ищу в Базе его, если всё нормально то работаю с ним. Кликаю по /index, то опять приходиться искать пользователя в базе, создаю объект и опять выстраиваю страницу под него. Как избежать поиск и создание нового объекта?

Comment: Кэшировать пользователя. Но лучше каждый раз запрашивать из базы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете попробовать кешировать пользователей, но это отразится на ресурсах. Можете так же хранить их в сессии, но это понизит безопасность приложения.

А на самом деле это нормально. И я бы на вашем месте начал задумываться над этим вопросом если бы только это действительно сильно сказывалось на скорости работы вашего приложения. Кажется это называется преждевременной оптимизацией.

К слову, подумал что вы, возможно, хотите сбежать не от постоянных запросов в базу, а от регулярного повторяющегося кода? в таком случае уже можно подумать как это решить со стороны организации самого кода.

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал что это костыли. Думал вдруг есть способ какой нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Так же не плохим вариантом будет работа с cookies, для подтверждения личности пользователя)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?